# How do I destroy a ActiveModel instance with dependant destroy children that have a default ordering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

In Rails 4.0 I have 2 ActiveRecord classes:

```
class Sequence < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :steps, dependent: :destroy

end
```

and

```
class Steps < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :sequence

    default_scope -> { order('order ASC') }

end
```

When I call `mySequence.destroy` I get this error:

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "order" LINE 1: ...steps" WHERE "steps"."sequence_id" = $1 ORDER BY order ASC ^ : SELECT "steps".* FROM "steps" WHERE "steps"."sequence_id" = $1 ORDER BY order ASC

When I remove the default scope, the error is gone, but I obviously have to order the steps in my sequence in my code.
I did try to define the association like this, and leaving out the default_scope statement:

```
class Sequence < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :steps, dependent: :destroy, order: 'order ASC'

end
```

but it threw the same error.

Does anyone else have this issue? Is this a bug in Rails? I imagine the ordering is not needed in the destroy sql statement on the children.

Comment: Can you try `mySequence.unscoped.destroy` with the above code you have in your `steps` class

Comment: Hmm, that produced
    undefined method `unscoped' for #<Sequence:0x007f086812c0b0>
Do you have a helper method for that? It does hint towards a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this issue on the rails gitHub issue page as well. [gitHub user tanraya](https://github.com/tanraya) suggested the following elegant solution.

```
default_scope -> { order order: :asc }
```

Thanks from over here, tanraya, and kudos!